# How to use set clipped path for Basemap polygon

Tags: python, matplotlib, gis, shapefile, matplotlib-basemap

I want to use imshow (for example) to display some data inside the boundaries of a country (for the purposes of example I chose the USA) The simple example below illustrates what I want:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import RegularPolygon

data = np.arange(100).reshape(10, 10)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
im = ax.imshow(data)
poly = RegularPolygon([ 0.5,  0.5], 6, 0.4, fc='none', 
                      ec='k', transform=ax.transAxes)
im.set_clip_path(poly)
ax.add_patch(poly)
ax.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

The result is:

[image]

Now I want to do this but instead of a simple polygon, I want to use the complex shape of the USA. I have created some example data contained in the array of "Z" as can be seen in the code below. It is this data that I want to display, using a colourmap but only within the boundaries of mainland USA.

So far I have tried the following. I get a shape file from [here](http://nationalatlas.gov/atlasftp.html?openChapters=chpbound#chpbound) contained in "nationp010g.shp.tar.gz" and I use the Basemap module in python to plot the USA. Note that this is the only method I have found which gives me the ability get a polygon of the area I need. If there are alternative methods I would also be interested in them. I then create a polygon called "mainpoly" which is almost the polygon I want coloured in blue:

[image]

Notice how only one body has been coloured, all other disjoint polygons remain white:

[image]

So the area coloured blue is almost what I want, note that there are unwanted borderlines near canada because the border actually goes through some lakes, but that is a minor problem. The real problem is, why doesn't my imshow data display inside the USA? Comparing my first and second example codes I can't see why I don't get a clipped imshow in my second example, the way I do in the first. Any help would be appreciated in understanding what I am missing.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap as Basemap
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

# Lambert Conformal map of lower 48 states.
m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-119,llcrnrlat=22,urcrnrlon=-64,urcrnrlat=49,
            projection='lcc',lat_1=33,lat_2=45,lon_0=-95)


shp_info = m.readshapefile('nationp010g/nationp010g', 'borders', drawbounds=True) # draw     country boundaries.

for nshape,seg in enumerate(m.borders):
    if nshape == 1873: #This nshape denotes the large continental body of the USA, which we want
        mainseg = seg
        mainpoly =  Polygon(mainseg,facecolor='blue',edgecolor='k')



nx, ny = 10, 10
lons, lats = m.makegrid(nx, ny) # get lat/lons of ny by nx evenly space grid.
x, y = m(lons, lats) # compute map proj coordinates.

Z = np.zeros((nx,ny))
Z[:] = np.NAN

for i in np.arange(len(x)):
    for j in np.arange(len(y)):
        Z[i,j] = x[0,i] 

ax = plt.gca()
im = ax.imshow(Z, cmap = plt.get_cmap('coolwarm') )
im.set_clip_path(mainpoly)
ax.add_patch(mainpoly)
plt.show()
```

## Update

I realise that the line

```
ax.add_patch(mainpoly)
```

does not even add the polygon shape to a plot. Am I not using it correctly? As far as I know mainpoly was calculated correctly using the Polygon() method. I checked that the coordinate inputs are a sensible:

```
plt.plot(mainseg[:,0], mainseg[:,1] ,'.')
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: I am also curious why I am getting down votes. Please tell me so that I can improve!

Comment: What have you tried? What are you asking?  Is the question really 'how do I simplify a path?' ? If so, why is it relevant that the path is the US?  Have you looked at any of the geometry libraries?  Presumably you want to close over the Chesapeake bay, maybe the Long Island Sound, but not the Gulf of Mexico.  The question is super open-ended, does not show much research effort, and reads as 'please do my work for me, give me teh codez!!1!' to cynical/cranky/jaded SO members.

Comment: Ok, I will update with some more information, thanks.

Comment: That is much better.

Comment: Thanks, I will update more if I make more progress, and I appreciate that help!

Comment: also, part of the problem may be that the blue face color on the patch has a higher z-oredr than your image and hence is hiding it.

Comment: I tried that, setting the colour to 'none' still yields no result. Im not really sure how to proceed to debug the instance "mainpoly" -I read the matplotlib.patches documentation but it is difficult to understand. Right now I'm just experimenting with all the methods that my Polygon object has, maybe that will tell me something.

Answer (score 3):

I have also considered about this problem for so long.
And I found NCL language has the function to mask the data outside some border.
Here is the example:

http://i5.tietuku.com/bdb1a6c007b82645.png

The contourf plot only show within China border. Click [here](https://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Applications/mask.shtml) for the code.

I know python has a package called PyNCL which support all NCL code in Python framework.
But I really want to plot this kind of figure using basemap. If you have figured it out, please post on the internet. I'll learn at the first time.

Thanks!

#### Add 2016-01-16

In a way, I have figured it out.
This is my idea and code, and it's inspired from this question I have asked today.

My method:
1. Make the shapefile of the interesting area(like U.S) into shapely.polygon.
2. Test each value point within/out of the polygon.
3. If the value point is out of the study area, mask it as np.nan

Intro
* the polygon xxx was a city in China  in ESRI shapefile format.
* fiona, shapely package were used here.

```
# generate the shapely.polygon
shape = fiona.open("xxx.shp")
pol = shape.next()
geom = shape(pol['geometry'])
poly_data = pol["geometry"]["coordinates"][0]
poly = Polygon(poly_data)
```

It shows like:

http://i4.tietuku.com/2012307faec02634.png

```
### test the value point 
### generate the grid network which represented by the grid midpoints.
lon_med  = np.linspace((xi[0:2].mean()),(xi[-2:].mean()),len(x_grid))
lat_med  = np.linspace((yi[0:2].mean()),(yi[-2:].mean()),len(y_grid))

value_test_mean = dsu.mean(axis = 0)
value_mask =  np.zeros(len(lon_med)*len(lat_med)).reshape(len(lat_med),len(lon_med))
for i in range(0,len(lat_med),1):
    for j in range(0,len(lon_med),1):
        points = np.array([lon_med[j],lat_med[i]])
        mask = np.array([poly.contains(Point(points[0], points[1]))])
        if mask == False:
            value_mask[i,j] = np.nan
        if mask == True:
            value_mask[i,j] = value_test_mean[i,j]


# Mask the np.nan value 
Z_mask = np.ma.masked_where(np.isnan(so2_mask),so2_mask)

# plot!
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(6,4))
ax=plt.subplot()

map = Basemap(llcrnrlon=x_map1,llcrnrlat=y_map1,urcrnrlon=x_map2,urcrnrlat=y_map2)
map.drawparallels(np.arange(y_map1+0.1035,y_map2,0.2),labels=  [1,0,0,1],size=14,linewidth=0,color= '#FFFFFF')
lon_grid  = np.linspace(x_map1,x_map2,len(x_grid))
lat_grid  = np.linspace(y_map1,y_map2,len(y_grid))
xx,yy = np.meshgrid(lon_grid,lat_grid)
pcol =plt.pcolor(xx,yy,Z_mask,cmap = plt.cm.Spectral_r ,alpha =0.75,zorder =2)
```

#### result

http://i4.tietuku.com/c6620c5b6730a5f0.png

http://i4.tietuku.com/a22ad484fee627b9.png

#### original result

http://i4.tietuku.com/011584fbc36222c9.png

Comment: Thanks- I admit haven't looked at this in a while but I'll let you know if something comes up.

Comment: Great. I'll try it too.