# how to mask the specific array data based on the shapefile

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

#### Here is my question:

- the 2-d numpy array data represent some property of each grid space
- the shapefile as the administrative division of the study area(like a city).

#### For example:

http://i4.tietuku.com/84ea2afa5841517a.png

The whole area has 40x40 grids network, and I want to extract the data inside the purple area. In other words , I want to mask the data outside the  administrative
boundary into np.nan.

#### My early attempt

I label the grid number and select the specific array data into np.nan.

http://i4.tietuku.com/523df4783bea00e2.png

```
 value[0,:] = np.nan
 value[1,:] = np.nan
       .
       . 
       .
       .
```

Can Someone show me a easier method to achieve the target?

#### Add

Found an answer [here](http://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/clip.html)    which can plot the raster data into shapefile, but the data itself doesn't change.

#### Update -2016-01-16

I have already solved this problem inspired by some answers.
Someone which are interested on this target, check this two posts which I have asked:
1. [Testing point with in/out of a vector shapefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34825074/testing-point-with-in-out-of-a-vector-shapefile)
2. [How to use set clipped path for Basemap polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25701321/how-to-use-set-clipped-path-for-basemap-polygon/34224925#34224925)

The key step was to test the point within/out of the shapefile which I have already transform into shapely.polygon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1. Rasterize shapefile

Create a function that can determine whether a point at coordinates `(x, y)` is or is not in the area. See [here](http://geospatialpython.com/2011/02/clip-raster-using-shapefile.html) for more details on how to rasterize your shapefile into an array of the same dimensions as your target mask

```
def point_is_in_mask(mask, point):
    # this is just pseudocode
    return mask.contains(point)
```

Step 2. Create your mask

```
mask = np.zeros((height, width))
value = np.zeros((height, width))
for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        if not point_is_in_mask(mask, (x, y)):
            value[y][x] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 3):

Best is to use `matplotlib`:

```
def outline_to_mask(line, x, y):
    """Create mask from outline contour

    Parameters
    ----------
    line: array-like (N, 2)
    x, y: 1-D grid coordinates (input for meshgrid)

    Returns
    -------
    mask : 2-D boolean array (True inside)
    """
    import matplotlib.path as mplp
    mpath = mplp.Path(line)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    points = np.array((X.flatten(), Y.flatten())).T
    mask = mpath.contains_points(points).reshape(X.shape)
    return mask
```

alternatively, you may use `shapely` contains method as suggested in the above answer. You may speed-up calculations by recursively sub-dividing the space, as indicated in this gist (but matplotlib solution was 1.5 times faster in my tests):

https://gist.github.com/perrette/a78f99b76aed54b6babf3597e0b331f8