# Clip a defined region in IRIS cube using a shapefile

Tags: python-2.7, cube, shapefile, clip, python-iris

I handle iris cubes containing meteorological data (lon, lat, precipitation, temperature,...) and I am interested in calculating statistics in defined areas (for example a country).

This [post](http://scitools.org.uk/iris/docs/v1.9.1/examples/Meteorology/COP_1d_plot.html#meteorology-cop-1d-plot) explains how to crop the cube with a box (min lon, min lat, max lon, max lat) but I would like to go a step further and select a precise area using a shapefile.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34585582/how-to-mask-the-specific-array-data-based-on-the-shapefile) explains that it is possible to crop an image using a shapefile associated to a mask, but I don't know how I can make it work for my iris cubes.

If somebody could give me an example or explain me how to do that it would be very useful.

PS: I am quite noobie with python

Answer (score 1):

Having read the shapefile using e.g. [Fiona](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Fiona) something like this should work:

```
from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint

# Create a mask for the data
mask = np.ones(cube.shape, dtype=bool)

# Create a set of x,y points from the cube
x, y = np.meshgrid(cube.coord(axis='X').points, cube.coord(axis='Y').points)
lat_lon_points = np.vstack([x.flat, y.flat])
points = MultiPoint(lat_lon_points.T)

# Find all points within the region of interest (a Shapely geometry)
indices = [i for i, p in enumerate(points) if region.contains(p)]

mask[np.unravel_index(indices)] = False

# Then apply the mask
if isinstance(cube.data, np.ma.MaskedArray):
    cube.data.mask &= mask
else:
    cube.data = np.ma.masked_array(cube.data, mask)
```

This only works for 2D cubes, but just needs tweaking for higher dimensions so that the mask is only over the lat/lon dimensions.

I actually implemented this behaviour in [CIS](https://github.com/cedadev/cis%20CIS) recently so that you can do `cube.subset(shape=region)` which might be easier for you.